# Progress bar in visual basics not working Like I want

Tags: vb.net

When My progress bar is finished loading it only responds when the progress bar is clicked on. I want it when the progress bar finishes loading it displays information. Here is my code:

```
  Private Sub ProgressBar1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ProgressBar1.Click
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        MsgBox("Done")
        TextBox1.Clear()
        TextBox2.Clear()
        TextBox3.Clear()
        TextBox4.Clear()
        TextBox5.Clear()
        TextBox6.Clear()
        ComboBox1.Refresh()
    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: So move your code to the code that finishes the progress.

Comment: Yeah, there's a bigger issue here outside the code you're showing.  Your code is in the handler for clicks, so of course it only runs when you click

Comment: No the problem is the progress bar finnishes loading but the action is progressbar1.click and i need to make it where it dispalys info as soon as the progress bar is done loading.

Comment: the progress bar does **do** anything, it reflects a value your code sets based on something.  Move that if block to where **you** are setting its value.

Comment: You put your code in a click handler. When do you expect it to run?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what code or object you are using to increment your `ProgressBar` but you need to be checking the value to the maximum where you are setting it. This example is using a Timer to increment it as an example. If this is not what you are wanting you need to be more precise in your question (our crystal balls don't always work reliably)

**Timer Tick Event**

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ProgressBar1.Value += 1
    If ProgressBar1.Value >= ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        MsgBox("Work Is Done")

    End If
End Sub
```